# Need a Function for Sequence Numbers

Tags: vba

I'm trying a function to get sequence between 2 values. Below given example for better understand.

1st Value = A1245
2nd Value = A1257

When I give above values in 'AddNum' function. It should give 'A1245,A1246,A1247' as result.

Below given vba code wrote by myself and i requesting you, please help on this.

```
Public x As Double

Function AddNum(Val1 As Variant, Val2 As Variant)

If Val1 = "" Or Val2 = "" Then
Exit Function
Else
x = -(Right(Val1, 4) - Right(Val2, 4))
End If

Dim myary As Variant
ReDim myary(x) As Variant

For y = LBound(myary) To UBound(myary)
Z = Right(Val1, 4) + y
myary(y) = Left(Val1, 2) & Z
ActiveCell.Offset(0, y + 1).Value = myary(y)
Next y

End Function
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are waiting.. Is Val1 / Val2 string ? or Range ? As a result you want a string ? A range ? What is the rule ? "You give A1257 but it's return until A1247".. Please explain what you expect of your function

Comment: @Sai Krishna have you tried any of the solutions provided below ? did they work as you intended ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're after something like this:

```
Sub AddNum(strng1 As Variant, strng2 As Variant)
    Dim val1 As Long, val2 As Long
    Dim code As String
    Dim iVal As Long

    If strng1 = "" Or strng1 = "" Then Exit Function

    code = Left(strng1, 1)
    val1 = CLng(Right(strng1, 4))
    val2 = CLng(Right(strng2, 4))

    ReDim myary(1 To val2 - val1 + 1) As String

    For iVal = val1 To val2
        myary(iVal - val1 + 1) = code & iVal
    Next iVal
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(myary)).Value = myary
End Sub
```

or you could exploit `Autofill()` method:

```
Sub AddNum2(strng1 As Variant, strng2 As Variant)
    Dim val1 As Long, val2 As Long
    Dim iVal As Long
    Dim code As String

    If strng1 = "" Or strng1 = "" Then Exit Sub

    code = Left(strng1, 1)
    val1 = CLng(Right(strng1, 4))
    val2 = CLng(Right(strng2, 4))

    With ActiveCell.Resize(, 2)
        .Value = Array(strng1, code & (val1 + 1))
        .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(, val2 - val1 + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @SaiKrishna, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that was the intention of your post, but if you want to get the result inside 1 Cell (the cell that call this `Function`) then you need to define this Function to return a `String`.

Also, the code assumes that you will call it with only 1 letter in the begining of a string (as a prefix), if you want to have the versatility to call this function with various letters in the begining, then you will need to add another parameter to the calling section.

**Code**

```
Function AddNum(Val1 As Variant, Val2 As Variant) As String

Dim MinVal, MaxVal
Dim i As Long
Dim CellStr As String, Prefix As String

If Val1 = "" Or Val2 = "" Then
    Exit Function
Else
    ' get the first letter on the left >> modify if you have more than 1 letter
    Prefix = Left(Val1, 1)

    ' read the "clean" value without the prefix and convert to Long
    MinVal = CLng(Mid(Val1, 2, Len(Val1) - 1))
    MaxVal = CLng(Mid(Val2, 2, Len(Val2) - 1))
End If

For i = MinVal To MaxVal
    If CellStr = "" Then
        CellStr = Prefix & i
    Else
        CellStr = CellStr & "," & Prefix & i
    End If
Next i
AddNum = CellStr

End Function
```